# javascript Letters only

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have created a quiz on javascript that once the user answers 4/6 or more correct they will then be asked for a First Name, Last Name and then be given a random 4 digit code. The part I'm having trouble with is making the FirstName and LastName letters only and also not allow and empty prompt.

Anyone know how i'd implement a Regex into this?

Anyone able to help?

```
function getAnswers(){         

var amountCorrect = 0;  

for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    var radios = document.getElementsByName('q'+i);

    for(var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++){

        var radio = radios[j];

        if(radio.value == "1" && radio.checked) {
            amountCorrect++;
        }
    }
}   

alert("Correct number of answers: " + amountCorrect + " / 6");

if (amountCorrect <= 3){
    alert("You have not passed on this occasion. You will now be taken back to the homepage.");
    window.history.go(-1); // Go back a step
}
else{
    var firstname = prompt("Please enter your first name.");
    var lastname = prompt("Please enter your last name.");
    alert("Your login Code for the store is: " + firstname.substring(1, 0) + lastname.substring(1, 0) + (generateCode())); // Do the generateCode function
    close();    
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add what you've tried to do? I don't see that anywhere in your code snippet

Comment: I removed it as I realised it was the totally incorrect way of implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
 var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$/;

    var firstname =prompt("Please enter your first name And Last Name","");
    if (firstname ==null || firstname =="")
    {
        alert("First and last name must be filled out!");
        location.reload(true);
    }
    else if (!firstname.matches(alphaExp))
    {
        alert("Name must contain letters only!")
        location.reload(true);
    }
   else{ // your code here.
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$
```

This regex matches a string of letters:

- Starting with the letter A-Z
- Only allow letters from a-z and A-Z
- It will not match an empty line or any other character.

Answer (score -2):

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

this will work for u.